# jquery remove class regardless of position

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, split

Need to grab any body classes besides one specifically. typically, i'd use `.split()`, but the position of the class might change. What's the best way to handle this?

HTML:

```
<body class="one two test"> || <body class="test three four">
```

JavaScript:

```
bod.attr('class').split('test')[0] || bod.attr('class').split('test')[1]
```

Thanks!

---

UPDATE:

I can't remove the `test` class. Stop downvoting a legitimate question.

Comment: There are two ways of looking at this: 1) how to remove a substring from anywhere in a string; 2) how to strip all instances of a value from an array of values.  You could do it either way, and it depends on whether you want to remove "test" before splitting or after.

Comment: Or is it that you want to remove all classes from the body *except* "test"? The question really isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to retrieve a list of classes other than the specified class, you should first build a list of the classes:

```
var classes = $('body').attr('class').split(' ');
```

...then remove the one you don't want:

```
classes.splice(classes.indexOf('test'), 1)
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7bk78/

Answer (score 3):

Just change it's class attribute to the one class you want to remain.

```
bod.attr('class', 'test')
```

Unless you also need the names of all of the other classes...

```
var otherClasses = bod.attr('class').split('test'); // either 1 or 2 element array (assuming your class name only shows up once)
bod.attr('class', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a regular expression:

```
var classes = document.body.className.replace(/\btest\b/g, '').split(/\s+/);
```

Then "classes" will be an array of the class values, but it won't include "test" in the list.